# C# + WinRT + Monogame threading for network (Azure Mobile Service) operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, windows-runtime, monogame

I have a loop in my application that loops through a set of entities in the following fashion

```
foreach(var entity in mEntities)
{
    entity.Update();
}
```

Some of these entities maintain a networking component that will call a Azure Mobile Service in order to update their state to the server. An example is below:

```
public class TestEntity {
    public int Index;
    public int PropertyValue;

    public async void Update()
    {
        Task.Run(() => {
            MyAzureMobileServiceClient.Update(Index, PropertyValue);
        });
    }
}
```

The UI rendering is done by Monogame in a more traditional game loop fashion. Whilst I do not know the inner workings of it, I am fairly certain that it does not have an actual separate thread doing the work. In practice, this shows as the UI freezing every time this update is called.

I want to be able to run it "smoothly" in the background. In the old Windows model this could have easily been done by starting a new Thread that would handle it, but I don't understand the threading well enough in WinRT to understand what is wrong with my approach.

Any ideas?

[update] I also tried this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    while(true) {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        MyAzureMobileServiceClient.Update(Index, PropertyValue);
    }
});
```

Every 1 seconds, I get a mini-freeze like before.

[update 2] I tried this with a twist. I replaced the Azure Mobile Service client call with a standard HTTP request and it worked splendidly; no mini-freezes. Granted it wasn't to the backend yet, but at least I have a work around by doing the whole thing manually. Would prefer to not do that, however.

[update 3] This is getting peculiar. I realize I simplified the code in this question in order to get it coherent in the context. However, this appears to have removed the true source of the problem. I tried the following things:

1. I created a HTTP request and created the request manually, called it inside the Task.Run() and it worked splendidly with no latency.
2. I called the Azure Mobile Service client Update DIRECTLY and there was no latency.

So this brings me to where the problem lies. I basically have a wrapper class for the Azure Mobile Service. The real path that goes looks roughly like this:

```
CommunicationClient.UpdateAsync(myObject);

public Task UpdateAsync(MyObjectType obj)
{
    var table = mMobileServiceClient.GetTable<MyObjectType>();
    return table.UpdateAsync(obj);
}
```

This causes the lag, but if I do this instead of it, it works with no latency whatsoever:

```
var client = CommunicationClient.MobileServiceClient;
var table = client.GetTable<MyObjectType>();
table.UpdateAsync(obj);
```

Soooooo... I should probably refactor the whole question. It's getting tl;dry.

Comment: It's a bit hard to see how all of the moving parts fit together here. Is it the data request that's causing the pause or updating the UI with the fetched data? If it's the latter, that's a much bigger challenge.

Comment: It's the latter and that would make it the challenge. Basically I don't currently even update the UI but just send a request. My original post was inaccurate to the extent that I am using Azure Mobile Service backend for my app. In practice this means sending an HTTP request and getting the response.

Maybe there is a stupid user error somewhere in my code that causes my Update thread to await for the response. I could probably delve deeper into how Monogame handles the rendering. If it helps, that Update() is called from the Monogame update loop.

Comment: I should add that the response I'm waiting for is a mere "200 OK" or "### Error". No actual data is required and I am not really interested in what is returned anyway. Furthermore, the data sent is a simple small "jsonized" struct containing a couple of strings and a few integers. That's to say that the amount of data moved is really small.

Comment: You may look into whether the scheduler is inlining your task onto the same thread instead of creating a new thread.  The default behavior in C# is to allow this. You can hint that it shouldn't by marking your task as long running. ie: Task.Factory.StartNew(Action, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

Answer (score 0):

I had a question about how to run things on a backgroundthread and they advised me to use ThreadPool so I would advise you to look at my question and the answer on it maybe you can pick up on some things and get it working on your end.

[Create Backgroundthread Monogame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161467/create-backgroundthread-monogame)